c++ framework drogon how to use different config.json for different environments?
When using the c++ framework drogon, the configuration I want to use for local development, e.g. mysql configuration is: localhost:3306.
Then when pushing the code to the test or main branch, I want to use the configuration xxx.com:3306.
How can I configure multiple config.json without having to change the same config.json when pushing code?
Simply put, i want to have two sets of config files, config.json and config.test.json, and then main.cc automatically loads different configs based on the environment, but I don't know how to achieve this.

You can load different config files with loadConfigFile("./config.json") depending on your environment.

OK, I knew the answer, just use environment variables to define the config file name.
